# Java Object memory usage - ibm jvm 1.4.2

Tags: java, profiling, memory-management

Is it possible to find memory usage of object in java within application?

I want to have object memory usage to be part of debug output when application runs.
I don't want to connect using external application to VM.

I have a problem that few classes eats up huge amount of memory and causes memory
problems, my app gets crash. I need to find that memory usage (I am working with limited memory resources).

**EDIT:** I am using java 1.4:/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390449/determining-java-memory-usage

Comment: @nc3b this link treats more about 1.5. Though worth noting is that url: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/instrumentation.shtml. Would love to have that in my java:/

Answer (score 6):

See my pet project, [MemoryMeasurer](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/). A tiny example:

```
long memory = MemoryMeasurer.measureBytes(new HashMap());
```

You may also derive more qualitative memory breakdown:

```
Footprint footprint = ObjectGraphMeasurer.measure(new HashMap());
```

For example, I used the latter to derive the [**per entry** cost of various data structures](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures), where the overhead is measured in number of objects created, references, and primitives, instead of just bytes (which is also doable). So, next time you use a (default) `HashSet`, you can be informed that each element in it costs 1 new object (not your element), 5 references, and an int, which is the exact same cost for an entry in `HashMap` (not unexpectedly, since any `HashSet` element ends up in a `HashMap`), and so on.

You can use it on any object graph. If your object graph contains links other structures you do wish to ignore, you should use a predicate to avoid exploring them.

**Edit** `Instrumentation` is not available to Java 1.4 (wow, people still use that?!), so the `memoryBytes` call above wouldn't work for you. But the second would. Then you can write something like this (if you are on a 32bit machine):

```
long memory = footprint.getObjects() * 8 + footprint.getReferences() * 4 +
              footprint.getPrimitives().count(int.class) * 4 + 
              footprint.getPrimitives().count(long.class) * 8 + ...;
```

That gives you an approximation. A better answer would be to ceil this to the closest multiple of 16:

```
long alignedMemory = (x + 15) & (~0xF); //the last part zeros the lowest 4 bits
```

But the answer might still be off, since if you find, say, 16 booleans, it's one thing if they are found in the same object, and quite another if they are spread in multiple objects (and cause excessive space usage due to aligning). This logic could be implemented as another [visitor](http://memory-measurer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dist/javadoc/objectexplorer/ObjectVisitor.html) (similar to how [MemoryMeasurer](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/source/browse/trunk/src/objectexplorer/MemoryMeasurer.java) and [ObjectGraphMeasurer](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/source/browse/trunk/src/objectexplorer/ObjectGraphMeasurer.java) are implemented - quite simply as you may see), but I didn't bother, since that's what `Instrumentation` does, so it would only make sense of Java versions below 1.5.

Comment: Nice tool, but I must verify 1.4 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is a really good tool to analyze memory.

Comment: Thanks, this seems nice but it is external tool. What I found out on theirs page http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer is <i> If you run your application with the VM flag -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  a heap dump is written on the first Out Of Memory Error.</i>. Though I doubt it will be supported in my java.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that comes with jdk such as jmap and jhat which provides object level details.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately those are external tools. I need to get that information inside as noted.

Answer (score 0):

The folowing link provides a piece of Java Code computing the size of objects:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip130.html

Comment: It is benchmark, not observation of memory usage within application livetime.