# Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: cannot open binary file

Tags: java, ubuntu, jmap

When I use jmap to get the heap info about a process, I got error like that:

```
$jmap -heap process_id

Attaching to process ID process_id, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: cannot open binary
file
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException:
cannot open binary file
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I have solved another error (`DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process`) by updating `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0`.

See: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7050524

Comment: Did you research the error you're getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmap can't connect to make a dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913948/jmap-cant-connect-to-make-a-dump)

Comment: You mean it is a permission problem? But I run this command by the same user with the java process.

Comment: After I restart my os, I start java process and use jmap again. There are no error. So it maybe permission probelm. But I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 32):

I faced the same issue, however when I `su`'d to the correct user having the relevant permissions the issue went away.

Comment: Interesting enought: Beeing `root` did not do the trick for me. I used `sudo -u THE__USER_RUNNING_THE_JVM ...` and then it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Saved me tons of time!

Answer (score 17):

Not directly related to the question asked. But, I encountered a similar error while using the **jstack** command while taking the thread dump of a java process. Let's say the pid of the java process for which I wanted thread dump is 1234.

I had used the command `jstack -l 1234 /home/users/a/thread-dump.txt`

What I missed in the above command is the redirection operator(>). The correct version of the command is

```
jstack -l 1234  > /home/users/a/thread-dump.txt
```

Maybe it helps someone :)

Comment: It is also a solution for "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address" error.

Answer (score 5):

This will also happen if you attempt to attach to an ineligible process so it's a good idea to reconfirm your pid.

For example, a friend of mine got this when they attempted to attach to the `jps` process they used to search for eligible pids ;).

Answer (score 3):

In our case, the java process was using `.../JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java` binary and the jmap process was using `.../JAVA_HOME/bin/jmap` binary.

Once we changed java process to use `.../JAVA_HOME/bin/java` binary, then the issue got resolved. We were able to run the jmap successfully.

Key is to use run the java process using JDK java binary instead of JRE java binary.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the solution for my problem. I spent days to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `jstack`. It turned out that I wasn't using Oracle JRE but OpenJDK as runtime for the process, but had only Oracle's JDK installed. Oracle's `jstack` cannot access an OpenJDK process. See also [Does OpenJDK have a tool similar to jstack (Oracle Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880183/does-openjdk-have-a-tool-similar-to-jstack-oracle-java)